# JQuery Autocomplete - JSON data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, laravel, autocomplete

I'm creating autocomplete to form. I get url with json data from backend (laravel/blade) in data-source' attribute that is in my input. I'm now able to display full JSON file in console logs but when I create a function that should display propositions when I type something in input doesn't work. There are no errors in dev tool. I want to get "loc_name" from json and send to backend "token". Do you have any tips for me?

**part of JSON**

```
[{"population":1729119,"token":"167|7|179|1296|55544|0","loc_name":"Warszawa"}]
```

**Blade.php - input**

```
{{Form::text('phrase', null, array('id' => 'city', 'data-container' => 'body',  'data-dropup-auto' => 'false',  'class' => 'mh__searcher__selectbar',  'tabindex'=>'-98','data-source' => URL::action('BPM\Controllers\Location\LocationController@getAutoCompleterLocation')))}}
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {

        var availableLocations = $('#city').attr('data-source');

        $("#city").on('keyup', function () {
            $.ajax({
                method: "get",
                url: availableLocations,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#city").autocomplete({
                        minLength: 0,
                        source: function (request, response) {
                            response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                                data, extractLast(request.term)));
                        },
                        focus: function () {
                            return false;
                        },
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            var terms = split(this.loc_name);
                            console.log(this.loc_name);
                            terms.pop();
                            terms.push(ui.item.loc_name);
                            terms.push("");
                            this.loc_name = terms.join(", ");
                            availableLocations.splice();
                            console.log(availableLocations);
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
        })
    })
```